# Macro That Shows Dialog Box Upon Close If Certain Condition Occurs For Multiple Excel Files in a Folder

Tags: vba, excel, macros

The following code loops through a bunch of .xlsx files in a folder and performs certain tasks such as insterting data validation in a specific cell range, conditional formatting within the same range and protecting the sheet and entire workbook to protect the integrity of the data. I would like to add one more piece of logic to the code below. **I would like to add code to have a dialiog box pop up informing a user of a missed responses in the data validation range.** So in simple terms, if person is required to enter a  response (Y or N) in a cell for a given amount of rows misses one, a dialog box will pop up when he or she closes the Excel to let them know. I don't wan't to restrict the person from saving file. Just to let them know that a response was missed. Thank you!

```
Sub ProtectSheetsAndDataValidation()
'
' Access_Review_Final Macro
'

   Dim MyFolder As String

   Dim myFile As String

   Dim wbk As Workbook

On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False



With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

.Title = "Please select a folder"

.Show

.AllowMultiSelect = False

   If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 'If no folder is selected, abort

MsgBox "You did not select a folder"

      Exit Sub

   End If

MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" 'Assign selected folder to MyFolder

End With

myFile = Dir(MyFolder) 'DIR gets the first file of the folder

'Loop through all files in a folder until DIR cannot find anymore

Do While myFile <> “”

   'Opens the file and assigns to the wbk variable for future use

   Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyFolder & myFile)

   'Replace the line below with the statements you would want your macro to perform

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Unable to open file " & myFile)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0


Sheets(1).Select
    Sheets(1).Name = "MAR"
    Cells.Select
    Range("K1").Activate
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("J1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("K4:K" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.Locked = False
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    Range("K4:K" & LastRow).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    Range("K4:K" & LastRow).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("K4:K" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=LEN(TRIM(K4))>0"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("J3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("K4").Select
    Range("K4:K" & LastRow).Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="Y,N,n,y"
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = False
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = "Invalid Response"
        .InputMessage = "Please Enter ""Y"" or ""N"". Case doesn't matter."
        .ErrorMessage = "Please Enter ""Y"" or ""N"". Case doesn't matter."
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Range("K11").Select
    Range("K16").Select
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Range("H3").Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowSorting:= _
        True, AllowFiltering:=True, Password:="adgiam"
    ActiveWorkbook.Protect Structure:=True, Windows:=False, Password:="adgiam"

ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9

wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True

myFile = Dir 'DIR gets the next file in the folder

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Macro has completed! Woot! Woot!"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Workbook_BeforeClose` event handler

what follows assumes that:

- worksheet "Validation" is to be checked for missing validation
- in worksheet "Validation", validation cells are in column K from row 4 down to last not empty row of column "B"

here's the code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim addrStrng As String

    With Worksheets("Validations")
        For Each cell In .Range("K4:K" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
            With cell.Validation
                .IgnoreBlank = False
                If Not .Value Then addrStrng = addrStrng & cell.address(False, False) & vbCrLf
            End With
        Next cell

        If addrStrng <> "" Then
            MsgBox "There are validation data input missing in: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & addrStrng
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @GaryDorman, It'd be nice of you giving feedbacks to people trying at helping you. Thank you